# const int transforms to int*

Tags: c++, constants, c++14

> /*the debug information suggests that the const int can not transform into int *,but when I change return &vec[i]; to return (int*)&vec[i]*/

```
int* find(const vector<int> &vec, const int value) {
        for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
            if (vec[i] == value) {
                cout << "找到该值得地址为：" << &vec[i] << endl;
                return &vec[i];
            }
        }
        return NULL;
    }
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

You say that the function will return a pointer to non-constant data, but then return a pointer to constant data (`vec` is constant, and so is the data inside of it). Constant and non-constant data are not the same.

The simple solution is to change the return type to `const int*`.